# MongoMapper -- Float updated via form: how to map "" => nil (instead of 0.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a rails3 project, using mongodb + MongoMapper. I have a model with a float value, which the user can set via a form. When the form is submitted, if no value is given for foo_val, the param is passed as the empty string, which winds up setting the attribute value to 0.0, which is not what I want. I want to differentiate between a user submitted value of "0", and user submitted "null" value (""), i.e. clearing the attribute.

How can I accomplish this?

```
class Foo
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :foo_val, Float

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer works - you could move it to the before_save action of the Document.  Another thing you could try is validates_numericality_of :foo_val, :allow_nil => true

That might work, supposedly it casts empty strings to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what I've figured out. There might well be a better way to do this:

I added a before filter in the Foo controller, to hook a function that checks my float params before create, update, edit, and save like so:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :nilify_float_params, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :edit]
  ...
protected
  def nilify_float_params 
    if params[:foo]
      params[:foo][:foo_value] = nil if params[:foo][:foo_value].empty?
    end
  end     
end
```